# Python yahoo finance data optimitzation

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I've found a code here pretty good to retrieve some data I need ([Python yahoo finance error market_cap=int(data.get_quote_yahoo(str)['marketCap']) TypeError: 'int' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58702437/python-yahoo-finance-error-market-cap-intdata-get-quote-yahoostrmarketcap)):

```
tickers=["AAPL","GOOG","RY","HPQ"]

# Get market cap (not really necessary for you)
market_cap_data = web.get_quote_yahoo(tickers)['marketCap']

# Get the P/E ratio directly
pe_data = web.get_quote_yahoo(tickers)['trailingPE']

# print stock and p/e ratio
for stock, pe in zip(tickers, pe_data):
    print(stock, pe)

# More keys that can be used
      ['language', 'region', 'quoteType', 'triggerable', 'quoteSourceName',
       'currency', 'preMarketChange', 'preMarketChangePercent',
       'preMarketTime', 'preMarketPrice', 'regularMarketChange',
       'regularMarketChangePercent', 'regularMarketTime', 'regularMarketPrice',
       'regularMarketDayHigh', 'regularMarketDayRange', 'regularMarketDayLow',
       'regularMarketVolume', 'regularMarketPreviousClose', 'bid', 'ask',
       'bidSize', 'askSize', 'fullExchangeName', 'financialCurrency',
       'regularMarketOpen', 'averageDailyVolume3Month',
       'averageDailyVolume10Day', 'fiftyTwoWeekLowChange',
       'fiftyTwoWeekLowChangePercent', 'fiftyTwoWeekRange',
       'fiftyTwoWeekHighChange', 'fiftyTwoWeekHighChangePercent',
       'fiftyTwoWeekLow', 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh', 'dividendDate',
       'earningsTimestamp', 'earningsTimestampStart', 'earningsTimestampEnd',
       'trailingAnnualDividendRate', 'trailingPE',
       'trailingAnnualDividendYield', 'marketState', 'epsTrailingTwelveMonths',
       'epsForward', 'sharesOutstanding', 'bookValue', 'fiftyDayAverage',
       'fiftyDayAverageChange', 'fiftyDayAverageChangePercent',
       'twoHundredDayAverage', 'twoHundredDayAverageChange',
       'twoHundredDayAverageChangePercent', 'marketCap', 'forwardPE',
       'priceToBook', 'sourceInterval', 'exchangeDataDelayedBy', 'tradeable',
       'firstTradeDateMilliseconds', 'priceHint', 'exchange', 'shortName',
       'longName', 'messageBoardId', 'exchangeTimezoneName',
       'exchangeTimezoneShortName', 'gmtOffSetMilliseconds', 'market',
       'esgPopulated', 'price']
```

I would like to retrieve most of the commented fields at the end of the previous code, but I've done this so far:

```
import pandas_datareader as web

tickers = ["AAPL", "GOOG", "RY", "SAB.MC"]

market_cap_data = web.get_quote_yahoo(tickers)['marketCap']
pe_data = web.get_quote_yahoo(tickers)['trailingPE']
fiftytwo_low_data = web.get_quote_yahoo(tickers)['fiftyTwoWeekLowChangePercent']


for stock, mcap, pe, fiftytwo_low in zip(tickers, market_cap_data, pe_data, fiftytwo_low_data):
    print(stock, mcap, pe, fiftytwo_low)
```

Obviously I could continue with my brute force, but do you know any way to make the code more elegant to retrieve the whole string of fields with column names?

```
['language', 'region', 'quoteType', 'triggerable', 'quoteSourceName',
       'currency', 'preMarketChange', 'preMarketChangePercent',
       'preMarketTime', 'preMarketPrice', 'regularMarketChange',
       'regularMarketChangePercent', 'regularMarketTime', 'regularMarketPrice',
       'regularMarketDayHigh', 'regularMarketDayRange', 'regularMarketDayLow',
       'regularMarketVolume', 'regularMarketPreviousClose', 'bid', 'ask',
       'bidSize', 'askSize', 'fullExchangeName', 'financialCurrency',
       'regularMarketOpen', 'averageDailyVolume3Month',
       'averageDailyVolume10Day', 'fiftyTwoWeekLowChange',
       'fiftyTwoWeekLowChangePercent', 'fiftyTwoWeekRange',
       'fiftyTwoWeekHighChange', 'fiftyTwoWeekHighChangePercent',
       'fiftyTwoWeekLow', 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh', 'dividendDate',
       'earningsTimestamp', 'earningsTimestampStart', 'earningsTimestampEnd',
       'trailingAnnualDividendRate', 'trailingPE',
       'trailingAnnualDividendYield', 'marketState', 'epsTrailingTwelveMonths',
       'epsForward', 'sharesOutstanding', 'bookValue', 'fiftyDayAverage',
       'fiftyDayAverageChange', 'fiftyDayAverageChangePercent',
       'twoHundredDayAverage', 'twoHundredDayAverageChange',
       'twoHundredDayAverageChangePercent', 'marketCap', 'forwardPE',
       'priceToBook', 'sourceInterval', 'exchangeDataDelayedBy', 'tradeable',
       'firstTradeDateMilliseconds', 'priceHint', 'exchange', 'shortName',
       'longName', 'messageBoardId', 'exchangeTimezoneName',
       'exchangeTimezoneShortName', 'gmtOffSetMilliseconds', 'market',
       'esgPopulated', 'price']
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the set, you can get all the items that can be retrieved by the ticker for the initial set, and using the union set, you can also add in a list, so you can get all the item names that have a value in the issue you want to retrieve.

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import pandas as pd

tickers = ["AAPL", "GOOG", "RY", "SAB.MC"]

names = set()
for t in tickers:
    market_cap_data = web.get_quote_yahoo(t)
    names |= set(market_cap_data.columns.to_list())
names

{'ask',
 'askSize',
 'averageAnalystRating',
 'averageDailyVolume10Day',
 'averageDailyVolume3Month',
 'bid',
 'bidSize',
 'bookValue',
 'cryptoTradeable',
 'currency',
 'customPriceAlertConfidence',
 'displayName',
  ...
 'trailingAnnualDividendYield',
 'trailingPE',
 'triggerable',
 'twoHundredDayAverage',
 'twoHundredDayAverageChange',
 'twoHundredDayAverageChangePercent',
 'typeDisp'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is pretty old, but I just came across it now. Check out the 'yfinance' library. There's all kinds of stuff available over there!!

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import pandas as pd
 
df = web.DataReader('AAPL', data_source='yahoo', start='2011-01-01', end='2021-01-12')
df.head()

import yfinance as yf
aapl = yf.Ticker("AAPL")
aapl
 
 
# get stock info
aapl.info
 
# get historical market data
hist = aapl.history(period="max")
 
# show actions (dividends, splits)
aapl.actions
 
# show dividends
aapl.dividends
 
# show splits
aapl.splits
 
# show financials
aapl.financials
aapl.quarterly_financials
 
# show major holders
aapl.major_holders
 
# show institutional holders
aapl.institutional_holders
 
# show balance sheet
aapl.balance_sheet
aapl.quarterly_balance_sheet
 
# show cashflow
aapl.cashflow
aapl.quarterly_cashflow
 
# show earnings
aapl.earnings
aapl.quarterly_earnings
 
# show sustainability
aapl.sustainability
 
# show analysts recommendations
aapl.recommendations
 
# show next event (earnings, etc)
aapl.calendar
 
# show ISIN code - *experimental*
# ISIN = International Securities Identification Number
aapl.isin
 
# show options expirations
aapl.options
 
# get option chain for specific expiration
opt = aapl.option_chain('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Result:

```
{'zip': '95014',
 'sector': 'Technology',
 'fullTimeEmployees': 164000,
 'longBusinessSummary': 'Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets smartphones, personal computers, tablets, wearables, and accessories worldwide. It also sells various related services. In addition, the company offers iPhone, a line of smartphones; Mac, a line of personal computers; iPad, a line of multi-purpose tablets; and wearables, home, and accessories comprising AirPods, Apple TV, Apple Watch, Beats products, and HomePod. Further, it provides AppleCare support and cloud services store services; and operates various platforms, including the App Store that allow customers to discover and download applications and digital content, such as books, music, video, games, and podcasts. Additionally, the company offers various services, such as Apple Arcade, a game subscription service; Apple Fitness+, a personalized fitness service; Apple Music, which offers users a curated listening experience with on-demand radio stations; Apple News+, a subscription news and magazine service; Apple TV+, which offers exclusive original content; Apple Card, a co-branded credit card; and Apple Pay, a cashless payment service, as well as licenses its intellectual property. The company serves consumers, and small and mid-sized businesses; and the education, enterprise, and government markets. It distributes third-party applications for its products through the App Store. The company also sells its products through its retail and online stores, and direct sales force; and third-party cellular network carriers, wholesalers, retailers, and resellers. Apple Inc. was incorporated in 1977 and is headquartered in Cupertino, California.',
 'city': 'Cupertino',
 'phone': '408 996 1010',
 'state': 'CA',
 'country': 'United States',
 'companyOfficers': [],
 'website': 'https://www.apple.com',
 'maxAge': 1,
 'address1': 'One Apple Park Way',
 'industry': 'Consumer Electronics',
 'ebitdaMargins': 0.33105,
 'profitMargins': 0.2531,
 'grossMargins': 0.43310001,
 'operatingCashflow': 122151002112,
 'revenueGrowth': 0.081,
 'operatingMargins': 0.30289,
 'ebitda': 130541002752,
 'targetLowPrice': 122,
 'recommendationKey': 'buy',
 'grossProfits': 170782000000,
 'freeCashflow': 90215251968,
 'targetMedianPrice': 180,
 'currentPrice': 151.29,
 'earningsGrowth': 0.048,
 'currentRatio': 0.879,
 'returnOnAssets': 0.21214001,
 'numberOfAnalystOpinions': 41,
 'targetMeanPrice': 178.15,
 'debtToEquity': 261.446,
 'returnOnEquity': 1.75459,
 'targetHighPrice': 214,
 'totalCash': 48304001024,
 'totalDebt': 132480000000,
 'totalRevenue': 394328014848,
 'totalCashPerShare': 3.036,
 'financialCurrency': 'USD',
 'revenuePerShare': 24.317,
 'quickRatio': 0.709,
 'recommendationMean': 1.9,
 'exchange': 'NMS',
 'shortName': 'Apple Inc.',
 'longName': 'Apple Inc.',
 'exchangeTimezoneName': 'America/New_York',
 'exchangeTimezoneShortName': 'EST',
 'isEsgPopulated': False,
 'gmtOffSetMilliseconds': '-18000000',
 'quoteType': 'EQUITY',
 'symbol': 'AAPL',
 'messageBoardId': 'finmb_24937',
 'market': 'us_market',
 'annualHoldingsTurnover': None,
 'enterpriseToRevenue': 6.317,
 'beta3Year': None,
 'enterpriseToEbitda': 19.081,
 '52WeekChange': -0.06042725,
 'morningStarRiskRating': None,
 'forwardEps': 6.82,
 'revenueQuarterlyGrowth': None,
 'sharesOutstanding': 15908100096,
 'fundInceptionDate': None,
 'annualReportExpenseRatio': None,
 'totalAssets': None,
 'bookValue': 3.178,
 'sharesShort': 103178670,
 'sharesPercentSharesOut': 0.0064999997,
 'fundFamily': None,
 'lastFiscalYearEnd': 1663977600,
 'heldPercentInstitutions': 0.60030997,
 'netIncomeToCommon': 99802996736,
 'trailingEps': 6.11,
 'lastDividendValue': 0.23,
 'SandP52WeekChange': -0.15323704,
 'priceToBook': 47.60541,
 'heldPercentInsiders': 0.00071999995,
 'nextFiscalYearEnd': 1727136000,
 'yield': None,
 'mostRecentQuarter': 1663977600,
 'shortRatio': 1.14,
 'sharesShortPreviousMonthDate': 1664496000,
 'floatShares': 15891414476,
 'beta': 1.246644,
 'enterpriseValue': 2490915094528,
 'priceHint': 2,
 'threeYearAverageReturn': None,
 'lastSplitDate': 1598832000,
 'lastSplitFactor': '4:1',
 'legalType': None,
 'lastDividendDate': 1667520000,
 'morningStarOverallRating': None,
 'earningsQuarterlyGrowth': 0.008,
 'priceToSalesTrailing12Months': 6.103387,
 'dateShortInterest': 1667174400,
 'pegRatio': 2.71,
 'ytdReturn': None,
 'forwardPE': 22.183283,
 'lastCapGain': None,
 'shortPercentOfFloat': 0.0064999997,
 'sharesShortPriorMonth': 103251184,
 'impliedSharesOutstanding': 0,
 'category': None,
 'fiveYearAverageReturn': None,
 'previousClose': 150.72,
 'regularMarketOpen': 152.305,
 'twoHundredDayAverage': 155.0841,
 'trailingAnnualDividendYield': 0.005971337,
 'payoutRatio': 0.14729999,
 'volume24Hr': None,
 'regularMarketDayHigh': 152.57,
 'navPrice': None,
 'averageDailyVolume10Day': 84360340,
 'regularMarketPreviousClose': 150.72,
 'fiftyDayAverage': 147.0834,
 'trailingAnnualDividendRate': 0.9,
 'open': 152.305,
 'toCurrency': None,
 'averageVolume10days': 84360340,
 'expireDate': None,
 'algorithm': None,
 'dividendRate': 0.92,
 'exDividendDate': 1667520000,
 'circulatingSupply': None,
 'startDate': None,
 'regularMarketDayLow': 149.97,
 'currency': 'USD',
 'trailingPE': 24.761045,
 'regularMarketVolume': 74496725,
 'lastMarket': None,
 'maxSupply': None,
 'openInterest': None,
 'marketCap': 2406736461824,
 'volumeAllCurrencies': None,
 'strikePrice': None,
 'averageVolume': 89929545,
 'dayLow': 149.97,
 'ask': 150.95,
 'askSize': 1000,
 'volume': 74496725,
 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh': 182.94,
 'fromCurrency': None,
 'fiveYearAvgDividendYield': 1,
 'fiftyTwoWeekLow': 129.04,
 'bid': 150.82,
 'tradeable': False,
 'dividendYield': 0.0061000003,
 'bidSize': 1100,
 'dayHigh': 152.57,
 'coinMarketCapLink': None,
 'regularMarketPrice': 151.29,
 'preMarketPrice': None,
 'logo_url': 'https://logo.clearb
```

Just pick/choose what you want.